# Push to new UIViewController from UICollectionView that's inside a UITableViewCell when tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

Currently I have the following code. The issue is that. on **didSelectItemAt** the xCode it's telling me that **navigationController** *(Type 'UINavigationController?' has no member 'pushViewController')*

for the following line:

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(searchCarViewController, animated: true)
```

I understand that its correct but just don't know the real solution for this. I'm new stacking CollectionViews on TableCells.

my Tree is:

UITableviewController -> UITableViewCell -> **UICollectionView** (here I get the tap event and try to push to another ViewController.) -> UICollectionViewCell

```
class MenuTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

var timerTest : Timer?

let menuOptions = [AppMenu(id:"1", name:"Buscar ", imageUrl:"search"),
                   AppMenu(id:"2", name:"Mis Datos", imageUrl:"datasheet"),
                   AppMenu(id:"3", name:"Tablas", imageUrl:"table"),
                   AppMenu(id:"4", name:"Preguntas", imageUrl:"faq")]

var myCollectionView: UICollectionView = {

    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20, right: 20)
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical

    let view = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    view.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true
    return view
}()

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    addSubview(myCollectionView)

    myCollectionView.delegate = self
    myCollectionView.dataSource = self
    myCollectionView.register(MenuCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "collectionCellId")
    myCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    myCollectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
    myCollectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    myCollectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    myCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    myCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return menuOptions.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionCellId", for: indexPath) as! MenuCollectionViewCell

    print(indexPath.row)
    let menu = menuOptions[indexPath.row]

    cell.nameLabel.text = menu.name
    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: menu.imageUrl)        
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: 160, height: 160)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let menu = menuOptions[indexPath.row]
    print(menu.name)

    let searchCarViewController = VehicleCategoryTableController()
    navigationController?.pushViewController(searchCarViewController, animated: true)

}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(searchCarViewController, animated: true)
```

inside a table cell instead you need to add this

```
weak var myParent:VCName?
```

then set it inside `cellForRowAt`

```
cell.myParent = self
```

then you can do this

```
myParent?.navigationController?.pushViewController(searchCarViewController, animated: true)
```

note you should have this hieracrchy

> UINavigationController->UITableviewController -> UITableViewCell -> UICollectionView

Another better way is to make the tableController as the delegate and dataSource of the collection like

```
cell.collectionView.delegate = self
cell.collectionView.dataSource = self
```

then implement the methods inside it and you can use your current code